# AWS Redshift: Error fetching values of DATE column. Consider using TIMESTAMP type instead

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

It is working for "greater than" functions not for less than.

For example:

```
select date_part('year',txndt)
from "table_name"
where date_part('year',txndt) > '2000' limit 10;
```

is working fine.

but for

```
select date_part('year',txndt)
from "table_name"
where date_part('year',txndt) < '2000' limit 10;
```

I am getting error.

> Error: Error fetching values of DATE column. Validate that DATE
>   columns match the corresponding file types. Consider using TIMESTAMP
>   type instead.

Comment: Please post the column definition used during CREATE TABLE for column txndt.

Comment: Looks like the txndt has a non date value. Try to select the distinct year converted to char and see if there is anything wrong with the data.

Comment: what does `select min(txndt),max(txndt) from "table_name";` return?

Comment: @JonScott    Issue is like, I have lakhs of rows of data. In which there is some date having like  0020-12-23 (which I have to remove) .  I have to take dates like
2012-11-11 (which are greater than 2000)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I have used txndt as DATE type

Comment: I was doing one more thing  but again stuck

My new logic is like -

select txndt FROM "tab_name" where txndt  like '20%';
this one is working fine.

but for 
select txndt FROM "tab_name" where txndt not like '20%';

same error reflected on sceen

Comment: The mention of `file types` is confusing. Are you using redshift spectrum to treat files in s3 as tables?  Also, `date_part()` returns an integer, so why are you comparing to a string?

Comment: Please do not tag questions for Redshift with Postgres. Although they share some common roots they are substantially different (Postgres doesn't even have such an error message as far as I know)

Comment: @MatBailie  I have tried for integer as well. But still same issue.

**bold**  select date_part('year',txndt) FROM "tab_name" where date_part('year',txndt) < 2000 limit 10;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am using Redshift connected on SQL workbench and it is using  Postgresql right?

Comment: Redshift is Redshift - it's a product on its own. There is no such thing as "Redshift using Postgres".

Comment: @Fact: Can you please ellaborate a bit what you told

Comment: You didn't answer as to whether you're using Redshift Spectrum.

Comment: I am using Redshift in SQL Workbench(both are integrated through driver).  - @MatBailie

Comment: I am using Redshift only which is connected to SQL Workbench through drivers.

@MatBailie

Comment: After long discussions and study, I got the answer today.

    select txndt FROM "table_name" where txndt  BETWEEN  '2000-01-01'  AND '2019-01-01';


This query is giving the proper output what I want.
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

After long discussions and study, I got the answer today.

```
select txndt FROM "table_name" where txndt  BETWEEN  '2000-01-01'  AND '2019-01-01';
```

This query is giving the proper output what I want.
Thanks to everyone.